# How to properly send action parameter along with query in BreezeJs

Tags: breeze

### Currently I am calling all data queries as showed on BreezeJs docs / examples:

```
getEntityList = function (predicate) {
  var query = new entityModel.EntityQuery().from("EntityList");
  if (predicate)
    query = query.where(predicate);
  return manager.executeQuery(query);
}
```

But I want to pass additional parameter to controller action before any queryable result is returned:

```
[AcceptVerbs("GET")]
public IQueryable<Entity> EntityList(string actionParam) {
  //here goes logic that depends on actionParam
  //and returns IQueryable<Entity>
}
```

As we know from documentation:

> Breeze converts the query into an OData query string such as this one:
>
> > ?$filter=IsArchived%20eq%20false&$orderby=CreatedAt

This is where the problem starts. How should I build query to pass param to controller action?

```
getEntityList = function (predicate, actionParam) {
  var query = new entityModel.EntityQuery().from("EntityList");
  if (predicate)
    query = query.where(predicate);
  if(actionParam)
    // ???
  return manager.executeQuery(query);
}
```

### I already tried setting route to:

```
routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{actionParam}",
            defaults: new { query = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
```

and sending *actionParam* by applying it in a *from* section,

```
var query = new entityModel.EntityQuery()
  .from("EntityList/" + encodeURIComponent(actionParam));
```

but encoding fails on some special chars and bad request is being thrown.

**How can I properly send *actionParam* in such scenario? Please help.**

Answer (score 24, accepted):

As of v 0.76.1, you can use the EntityQuery.***withParameters*** method to pass additional parameters to any service method.  So you can now construct a query like the following that both passes parameters and uses breeze's IQueryable support.

```
EntityQuery.from("EmployeesFilteredByCountryAndBirthdate")
                 .withParameters({ BirthDate: "1/1/1960", Country: "USA" })
                 .where("LastName", "startsWith", "S")
                 .orderBy("BirthDate");
```

where your controller method would look something like this:

```
[HttpGet]
public IQueryable<Employee> EmployeesFilteredByCountryAndBirthdate(DateTime birthDate, string country) {
      return ContextProvider.Context.Employees.Where(emp => emp.BirthDate >= birthDate && emp.Country == country);
}
```

The API docs have more information.

Answer (score 6):

UPDATE: AS OF BREEZE v.0.76.1 THIS IS NO LONGER THE CORRECT ANSWER. BREEZE NOW SUPPORTS PARAMETERS ON QUERIES. SEE THE "***withParameters***" QUERY CLAUSE.

Support for parameterized queries was added to Breeze thanks in part to this question on SO. Thank you.

This answer used to describe a workaround which is no longer needed. I have revised my answer, eliminating my description of that workaround.

Comment: It would be nice to have a place at http://www.breezejs.com  where you post short info about what's coming soon.

Comment: It's not the most important thing for me to deal with so I can wait.

Comment: This is NO LONGER THE RIGHT ANSWER. As I hoped, the "withParameters" feature was added to Breeze in v.0.76.1 and is described in Jay's answer. I'm up-voting his. As promised, I'm removing the referenced web page to the hack. Please use "withParameters"