# BreezeJS Query and filter via an entities collections entity

Tags: breeze

I have the following model:

```
Products (DbSet<Product>)
ProductHasWidgets (DbSet<ProductHasWidget> many-to-many w/ payload)
Widgets (DbSet<Widget>)
```

I am getting stuck with querying across and/or from the many-to-many table and have two questions:

How do I write a breeze query to return all Products where:

1. `Widget.IsActive == true`
2. `ProductHasWidgets.WidgetId == 1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do that from a Breeze client yet because Breeze does not support the `any` keyword at this time.

You can write a service method to do the query on the server. The client can pass query parameters to that method using the BreezeJS `withParameters` query verb.

Comment: Perfect!  Thanks Ward!  I found this link which shows a working example-- <http://stackoverflow.com/a/13793910/1265146>  For others looking for this answer.

Answer (score 0):

As of Breeze 1.4.6, Breeze now supports "any" and "all" queries.  See: http://www.breezejs.com/documentation/query-examples

Depending on your model, this means that your query would look something like:

```
var predicate = breeze.Predicate.create("WidgetId", "==" 1)
  .and("Widget.IsActive", "==", true);
var query = EntityQuery.from("Products")
    .where("ProductHasWidgets", "any", predicate);
```