# Using Breeze query not invoking action

Tags: breeze, hottowel

I am developing single page application using HotTowel.
My question is that, When I am writing a Breeze query with string parameter whose length is greater than 1600 characters then action is not invoking.

Please let me know the reason.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer from @fops is correct.  Using `.withParameters`, you may be able to create some methods on your server that allow you to use some shorthand on the client instead of very large queries.

If your queries are really big, and even `.withParameters` blows up your URL, you may need to use POST instead of GET.

Breeze doesn't support POST for queries directly, but there's an (unsupported) add-on in [Breeze Labs](http://www.breezejs.com/breeze-labs/) called [breeze.ajaxpost.js](http://www.breezejs.com/breeze-labs/breezeajaxpostjs) that will let you use POST for `.withParameters` queries.

Answer (score 2):

as stated in:

[What is the maximum length of a URL in different browsers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/417142/what-is-the-maximum-length-of-a-url-in-different-browsers)

there is a limit for the length of urls

check parametrized queries as a possible workaround:

[How to properly send action parameter along with query in BreezeJs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13704466/how-to-properly-send-action-parameter-along-with-query-in-breezejs)